# Check multiple checkboxes by ID

Tags: jquery, html, css

A simple I think but annoying issue.

I'm trying to check all checkboxes that have a particular ID attribute, it's currently only checking the first one.

```
$("#goUS").click(function()
   {
      $("#checkUS").each(function()
      {
      $("#checkUS").prop("checked", true);
      });
   });
```

I've found similar questions but none that answered my question.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: IDs should be unique in the DOM. You should not have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: This is the flaw in the plan: "all checkboxes that have a particular ID attribute".... The whole point of an **ID** (in all walks of life, not just programming) is that it should be **unique**. Any elements with the same ID subsequent to the first one are considered invalid for the purpose of identifying them via a # selector. Just the same as if you cashed a cheque with a particular ID and then tried to cash another copy with the same ID. Use classes instead if you need to target a group of elements.

Comment: Can you show your html code? I think the problem might be that the selector `$("#checkUS")` just returns one element because an id is supposed to be unique, and therefore there shouldn't be multiple elements with the same id. Try using classes. If you post your html code i can post an answer on how i would solve that.

Comment: Hi Sorix, Thomas and especially ADyson who fixed my issue, all of you are right, but ADyson suggesting moving to classes fixed my issue. ADyson if you post this as an answer I will mark this as the correct answer. Thanks to all again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the flaw in the plan:

> "all checkboxes that have a particular ID attribute"....

The whole point of an ID (in all walks of life, not just programming) is that it should be **unique**. Any elements with the same ID subsequent to the first one are considered invalid for the purpose of identifying them via a # selector.

Use classes instead if you need to target a group of elements. You don't even need a loop in this case:

```js
$("#goUS").click(function() {
  $(".checkUS").prop("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="goUS">Check</button>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkUS" />1
<input type="checkbox" class="checkUS" />2
<input type="checkbox" class="checkUS" />3
<input type="checkbox" class="checkUS" />4
```

Answer (score 1):

The `id` value represents a unique identifier for a given element. That is, no two elements on the same page can have the same id. That being said, there is no way for jQuery to locate "all" elements with the same id, since there is at most one element with a given id.

Instead of identifying elements in a group with a constant `id`, consider adding a `data-*` attribute to them and selecting them based on that.

More info on `data-*`:

- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Probably chooses item first. Use the `this` selector this to resolve this issue. Is a working example

```js
  $("#goUS").click(function() {
    $("input[id^='checkUS']").each(function() {
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="goUS">Check</button>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkUS">1
<input type="checkbox" id="checkUS">2
<input type="checkbox" id="checkUS">3
<input type="checkbox" id="checkUS">4
```

Comment: this is an inefficient workaround. The HTML is still invalid. Duplicate IDs are not allowed, which is why the original code didn't work. Fix problems in the correct way rather than using a bodge to avoid the issue.